Integrate landing page in angular
I need a little help, I have a landing page created with HTML, CSS and Jquery, and I have a project in Angular, what I am looking to do is have the Landing page be displayed on the main domain (mydomain.com) and when I click on a login button it sends me to mydomain.com/sign-in which would already be the project in Angular.
I hope both projects work on the same domain

axe JQuery and re-create your landing page as an angular component.
